# Redirect from java filter to a different AngularJS page

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-security, filter

When I tried to find the solution for the challenge I'm facing at the moment, I was provided with many approaches which didn't seem to quite fit my problem.
Here's what I'm facing:

I have a back-end integrated with `Spring Security` and the front-end is all built using `AngularJS`. We have 2 sets of users - legacy and new. The new feature requires when a legacy user signs in, redirect the user to the password reset page and have the legacy user reset his password to meet the new password standards.

This is the approach I have taken to deal with this:
Create a filter that intercepts every user request, checks if the user is a legacy user or not. If he is, redirect the user to the password reset page.

The challenge I'm facing at the moment is to let AngularJS know from the filter that it should redirect the user to the password reset page.

When I call sendRedirect on the `HttpServletResponse`, it's not redirecting to the destination page. I know I'm missing something here. Can someone help me with the approach here?

Thanks.

Comment: You should check the response status from the login request in your angular app. If the response status is a REDIRECT, then do a redirect in your angular app. You cant send a redirect from the backend api and expect that the angularjs app will understand it and do the redirect by itself.

Comment: I gave a thought on that but was just wondering if there's any other better approach that I may not be aware of either in AngularJS or in the back-end. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dvorog said in his comment, you have to send a redirect response to your client, such as 302. You should specify the redirect location in the header.

Then, in client side, you can manage the header in the error callback

```
$http.get('/someUrl').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // check status and get headers informations(ie location) here to make redirection
});
```

You will find more detail in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Not an expert in AngularJS. But does implementing interceptor help me here in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a better solution (in the comments) this is what I would do:

Create a guard that will be assigned on all of the routes that require the user to be authenticated in order to access them. This guard should check the role of the authenticated user, and if the user is a legacy one, then redirect the user to the "change password" site. This way, you won't have to implement special logic on the backend and send redirect requests.

Comment: Guard? I will keep that in mind. Thanks.

After reading on some more on this, I came across AngularJS interceptors. I'm not that adept in AgularJS. Do you think implementing interceptors would be a good idea in this case?

Comment: As far as I know, interceptors will intercept any request that goes out or in your app. For example, you might have components that are only accessible to the other type of users and there is no need to check if those users have updated their passwords or not. With guards, you can assign the specific guard only to the components you want validated, while in the other case, you can't choose which requests should be checked.